# I am binding a service to an app in Cloud Foundry. What's the URL to call service APIs?

Tags: cloud-foundry, predix

Followed the Pivotal CloudFoundry tutorial (https://pivotal.io/platform/pcf-tutorials/getting-started-with-pivotal-cloud-foundry) and pushed an app, cf-spring-unspent-autoradiography.run. Then bound a service to the app and pushed it, using CF Push. Now, I'd like to communicate with the bound service (API) via a third party app. Doable? If so, what's the destination URL / header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to parse VCAP_SERVICES environment variable for service- specific credentials/urls

https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html

Comment: I'm assuming from the name that the app is a Java Spring app. If so, you can use the Spring Cloud Connectors library to assist with parsing VCAP_SERVICES and creating necessary connection beans. http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can see the service dashboard which you bound with an app. Click on your service instance in services tab. You can find **Manage** link - once you clicked it will redirect to your service dashboard.

Following links are **Docs** and **Support** in service instance page. Docs link will give detailed information about service and support link will help you to solve any issues.